# trying to call superclass method in subclass

Tags: java, subclass, superclass

Probably a pretty noob question, but I cant figure it out. I have a class Person to store a name that is input from the keyboard

```
public class Person {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public Person()
    {
        firstName = "";
        lastName = "";
    }

    public Person(String first, String last)
    {
        setName(first, last);
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return(firstName + " " + lastName);
    }

    public void setName(String first, String last)
    {
        firstName = first;
        lastName = last;
    }

    public String getFirstName()
    {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName()
    {
        return lastName;
    }
}
```

I am trying to call the toString method in a subclass called Patient

```
public class Patient extends Person {
    private int patientID, patientAge;
    public Patient()
    {
       patientID = 0; //for a different part of the class that works
       patientAge = 0;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return ("Patient Name: "+super.toString());
    }
}
```

I cannot get it to output the name in main when I call the toString method from the Patient class, but when I tested it, it output the name when I call the toString method from the Person class. 
The method call in main looks like `Patient pnt = new Patient();` `System.out.print(Pnt.toString());`
it prints out in the console "Patient Name: ". Any feedback on what I am doing wrong or ideas on how to get it to work

Comment: How are you constructing your `Patient` object? Looks like the first and last name aren't getting set.

Comment: Please post your main method

Comment: Just for the record, as newbies often forget about that: please dont forget to accept an answer at some point!

Comment: the problem is that u dont set the name. now the solutions are already suggested on comments. either use your setters or telescoping constructors and set the name in your main or subclasses constructor(s). also remember that the setters are inherited so u can construct a patient, use setters for name and print it

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
public Person()
{
    firstName = "";
    lastName = "";
}
```

Your subclass is missing a **reasonable** call to a super class constructor. So when you instantiate your Patient objects, the above constructor is used, and all patients end up with "" as first and last name!

When you create a Patient, then a patient should have a **name**, too! But your constructor in Patient only sets the Patient related fields. And implicitly, the default super constructor is called. Therefore the Person fields are all set to be empty strings!

A much better approach would look like this:

```
class Person {
  private final String firstName;
  ... lastName

  public Person(String firstName, String lastName) {
   this.firstName = firstName;
  ...
```

and then

```
class Patient extends Person {
  private final int patientID;

  public Patient(int patientID, String firstName, String lastName) {
    super(firstName, lastName);
    this.patientID = patientID;
  )
```

Why is that better: names and IDs don't change (normally). There is no point in having getters for them. You create your object once, and then that data is fixed! There is also **no** point in having that default constructor in Person. A person with **empty** names doesn't make sense. Thus: don't create a class that allows you to create "invalid" objects. Your classes *model* reality. There are no real people without names!

And one other hint: use @Override when overriding methods, so that the compiler can tell you when you get something wrong!

Answer (score 0):

I have added some comments and code in your Person class that should fix your issues.

```
public class Person {
private String firstName; //store the first name
private String lastName; //sore the last name

//initialize firstName and lastName to an empty string
public Person() {
    firstName = "";
    lastName = "";
}

//set firstname and lastname according to the parameters.
public Person(String first, String last) {
    //setName(first, last); remove this crap.
    // Use the contructor properly when initialize your person object. Like this:
    this.firstName = first;
    this.lastName = last;
}

//method to output the first name and last name
@Override
public String toString() {
    return (firstName + " " + lastName);
}

//method to set firstName and lastName according to the paramters
public void setName(String first, String last) {
    //
    firstName = first;
    lastName = last;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if the problem is to output the name in main when you call the `toString` method from the Patient class, I think the code bellow will help you.

have you tried to construct the `Patient` object like this?

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Patient p = new Patient();
    System.out.println(p.toString());

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually I do not see problem in your code.

```
Person person = new Person();
person.setName("aa", "bb");
System.out.println(person);  // aa bb

Patient patient = new Patient();
patient.setName("cc", "dd");
System.out.println(patient);  // Patient Name: cc dd
```

I think that you set name wrong pr use not correct reference. Check it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any constructor for your **PATIENT** subclass. You don't set any firstName or lastName to any patient.
To keep familiar constructor as you used in your parent class, tru to use:

```
public Patient() {
    super("default_firstName", "default_lastName");
    this.patientID = 0;
    this.patientAge = 0;
}
public Patient(String firstName, String lastName, int patientAge) {
    super(firstName, lastName);
    this.patientID = 0; //can be implemented some method for automatically setting numbers
    this.patientAge = patientAge;
}
```

This way you always get firstName and lastName even if constructor will be called empty.
According to you **toString** method, it's correct and it call super class method:

```
@Override
public String toString()
{
    return("Patient name is "+super.toString());
}
```

But notice that you return STRING value so to make it visible on the screen remember to use:

```
System.out.println(patient.toString());
```

Then it will be visible :)